# How to export date time as per my timezone in odoo 11?

Tags: python, odoo-11

I tried to export datetime field of Attendance but i am getting wrong date time value. It is giving UTC date time instead my my timezone datetime.

How can i resolve this issue? Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just update in main.py file of controller of Web module. You can do this in inherit the main.py file.

Import below package in main.py

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
import datetime
import pytz
```

-->Update in CSVExport class for CSV. Add below code in this class.

```
def check_date(self, value):
try:
    parse_data = parse(value)
    return parse_data
except Exception as e:
    return False
```

Update from_data() function like below code.

```
def from_data(self, fields, rows):
   fp = io.BytesIO()
   writer = pycompat.csv_writer(fp, quoting=1)
   writer.writerow(fields)
   for data in rows:
     row = []
     for d in data:
        if isinstance(d, pycompat.string_types) and d.startswith(('=', '-', '+')):
            d = "'" + d
        if type(d) is str:
            parse_data = self.check_date(d)
            if parse_data:
                if len(d) > 10:
                    tz = pytz.timezone(request._context.get('tz'))
                    d = (pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime.strptime(d,'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')).astimezone(tz)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        row.append(pycompat.to_text(d))
     writer.writerow(row)
  return fp.getvalue()
```

-->For Excel Update below code in ExcelExportV class in datetime condition.

```
elif isinstance(cell_value, datetime.datetime):
  tz = pytz.timezone(request._context.get('tz'))
  cell_value = (pytz.utc.localize(cell_value).astimezone(tz)).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  cell_style = datetime_style
```

After that, restart your odoo service and check.